# List of tuples in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Given a list of tuples `asd :: [(Char, Char)]`, I want to write a function that takes in a string and returns the same string, with characters matching the first element of tuples in `asd` replaced with the corresponding second element.

For example, with `asd = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]`, with input `"ac"`, it should return `"bd"`.

I also want to write a function that does the reverse, which when given input `"bd"` should return `"ac"`.

I have a solution, but I can't use list generator and recursion.

This is my solution:

```
xyz :: String -> String
xyz x = concat (map y x) where  y ys = [a | (b,a) <- asd, ys == b]

zyx x :: String -> String
zyx x = concat (map y x) where y ys = [a | (a,b) <- asd, ys == b]
```

How can I write this without recursion and list generator?

Comment: Hint: use `filter`.

Comment: How should your functions `xyz` and `zyx` handle characters not in the list of tuples? For example, should `xyz "abc"` return `"bbd"` or `"bd"`?

Answer (score 1):

*Pending clarification regarding exact specification in comments, I am assuming that you want to replace characters while keeping non-matching as-is.*

---

To apply a function to each element of a list (a `String` is just `[Char]`), use [`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). Hence, you will need to write a map on the input string like so

```
xyz :: String -> String
xyz = map replace
```

This `replace` function should run through the list of tuples `asd`, and find the first tuple that matches. (I'm making an assumption here as it wasn't specified how to handle having more than one matching tuple.) To do this, we make use of [`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) to find which tuples are matching.

```
replace :: Char -> Char
replace c = case filter ((== c) . fst) asd of
                ((_, c'):_) -> c' -- found a replacement
                []          -> c  -- no match, don't replace character
```

where `((== c) . fst)` compares the first element of the tuple to the character `c`.

Lastly, to implement the reverse function, simply do the same thing but with the replacement looking up by the second element instead, like so

```
zyx :: String -> String
zyx = map replace'

replace' :: Char -> Char
replace' c = case filter ((== c) . snd) asd of
                ((c', _):_) -> c' -- found a replacement
                []          -> c  -- no match, don't replace character
```

---

*Reference links for [`fst`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:fst) and [`snd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:snd).*